# Cannot assign jQuery Timepickers in 2 differents Text Input.

Tags: jquery, html, timepicker

I have two `Timepickers`. Problem is though that both timepickers belong to one *text input* (*start time* input) when they should belong to 2 different ones.

*durationpicker* is for the *duration* input and *timepicker* is for the *start time* one.

How can I seperate the timepickers so they belong to the right input ?

below is jQuery code:

```
$('#durationpicker').timepicker({});

$(function() {
    $('#timepicker').timepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        button: '.timepicker_button_trigger'
    });
});
```

And the HTML :

```
 <form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">
   <p>
     <strong>3: Duration:</strong>
     <input type="text" id="durationpicker" name="durationChosen" readonly="readonly"/>
   <p>
    <strong>5: Start Time:</strong>
    <input type="text" id="timepicker" name="timeChosen" readonly="readonly" />
    <span class="timepicker_button_trigger">
      <img src="Images/clock.gif" alt="Decrease" />
    </span> <br/>
    <span id="dateTimeAlert"></span>
  </p>
</form>
```

Note : I am using [Trentrichardson's Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) for duration input and [François Gélinas](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) for start time input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `#durationpicker`'s timepicker outside of the "document ready" function, it won't work.

Try moving it near the other one.